# In a MySql trigger, how to set an attribute's to be the original value +1

Tags: mysql

```
delimiter |
create trigger createComment
after insert on comment
for each row
begin
update commentCount 
set comment_count = comment_count+1
where user_id in (select user_id from blogList where blog_id = new.blog_id);
end;
| delimiter ;
```

I tried like this, but the value of comment_count didn't change.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my recommendation:

```
delimiter |
create trigger createComment
after insert on comment
for each row
begin
    update commentCount cc
        set comment_count = coalesce(comment_count, 0) + 1
    where cc.user_id in (select bl.user_id from blogList bl where bl.blog_id = new.blog_id);
end;
|
delimiter ;
```

However, this is quite similar to your code.  If nothing is being updated, then the `blogList` table might be suspect, or the user might not be in the `CommentCount` table.  For the latter, use:

```
begin
    insert into commentCount(user_id, comment_count)
        select user_id, 1
        from bloglist bl
        where bl.blog_id = new.blog_id
        on duplicate key update comment_count = comment_count + 1;
end;
```

Be sure that `commentCount(user_id)` is either a primary key or unique key on the table.

Answer (score -1):

It may be better to rename the table to comments(plural) and possibly to use underscores in the field name instead of camelCase.

It would look something like:

```
UPDATE comments SET counter=counter+1 WHERE ...
```